# Conditional Style to Remove Line Chart Series

Tags: cognos, cognos-10

We are using Cognos 10.1.1.

In report studio we need to display a chart series based on the user role. For example, if the user that is logged in is not a member of the Sys Admin role, then do not render Series A, however continue to render Series B and C.

We already have logic in place to get the user role, so that's not an issue. The problem is we cannot seem to find anywhere to add a conditional style to the chart series to accomplish our goal. We've messed around with putting logic directly in the query to make the values all null which removes all the points and line from the chart, but it still displays the series name in the legend. We are looking for a clean way to just drop the series from the chart.

Is there a way to do this with conditional styles? If so how? If not does anybody know how to accomplish this?

Comment: Look into render variables.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have manually configured elements as series A, B, C? If you just had a list of “Series” in legend and than applied security to it — it would be filtered out.

If you have manually defined series elements — the only options is render variables for each and every series item as Andrew said, but I would try to avoid it. It can be tedious to set up if you have multiple series in chart. And maintenance would be a pain. I'd try create a list of series and then use if then else expressions to capture your current manual definitions.